# Blocking Request to Jetty Server

Tags: java, jetty

If I have a client requesting data from a Jetty Server as such:

```
private static MessageBean fetchMessage(final String host, final int hostPort, final String path) {
  return client.target(String.format("http://%s:%d/%s", host, hostPort, path))
      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
      .get(new GenericType<StateMessageBean>() {
      });
}
```

then I want the following behavior:

When a boolean variable is false i want the Jetty Server to send nothing and the client to block infinitely until boolean variable is true. Else I want Jetty Server to send a response.

In order to be better understood my question the code of the server method I want it to look like this:

```
  @GET()
  @Path("/message")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public MessageBean getMessage() {
    final MyStore<String, String> myMessageStore = ...
    String message = messageStore.readMessage();

    boolean messageState = myMessageStore.readBoolean(); 

    if(messageState)
    return new StateMessageBean(message);
    else
    //return something in order for the client to block infinitely
}
```

Or is there another pattern that I am missing in order for the jetty server to send nothing and for the client to wait?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
while(!messageState) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    messageState = myMessageStore.readBoolean();
}
```

But this is not suggested for web servers because worker threads will pretty quickly run out. If you want to deny service to a client then you should immediately return a 403 or something. Otherwise you could DROP on the firewall level, but, of course, connecting this firewall decision to your `messageState` variable may not be trivial.